# Haversine formula from a set starting point: Why don't my results make sense?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use the Haversine formula to calculate distance from a set starting point (Row 2 of the attached image). I've previously used the Haversine formula to calculate distance between points with no issue (See rows 16-27), however, I'm trying to change the formula to the purpose I mentioned above.

I tried just changing the previous beginning point value to, for example, $F$2 for my Lat_1 value and $G$2 for Lon_1 and letting Lat 2 and Lon 2 increase as I apply the formula to each cell. With this method, shouldn't the output increase as I go down the rows?

Perhaps it's an artifact of the fact that the sample transect isn't a perfectly straight line; is there a way to only calculate the westward distance from my starting point? [Here is a link to my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXM76.png)

Comment: Please post your formula into the body of your question. This will help in answering the question.

Comment: Did you need to remove $ from your fromula?